# How to detect if Powershell Core is installed and what version in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-core

With Windows Powershell it is possible to lookup the installed version within the registry.

Using C#, what is the most reliable way to determine if Powershell Core (6+) is available on a system, as well as what version?

*Note: I appreciate it can be deployed via zip which complicates this, so specifically looking for "installed" instances.*

Comment: This link can help. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55619139/checking-installed-powershell-version-from-c-sharp)

Comment: That link nor the incorrectly flagged duplicate help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question to yours: [Get installed applications in a system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system). It talks more generally about getting installed applications with C#, but you should be able to adapt it to fit your needs.

Powershell Core v6+ & v7+ show up in the installed programs list separately unlike the Powershell install embedded in Windows.